# combining multiple joins in one SQL statement

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have three tables in my database schema: MY_TABLE, CREATIVE_SIZE, REVERSE_CREATIVE_SIZE

`MY_TABLE` consists of three columns

```
|            NAME             |   BANNER_W  |  BANNER_H |
|     320x480_Toyota          |     320     |   480     |
| Tim_Horton_IO00122_1024x320 |     1024    |   320     |
|     Walmart_IO00134         |     80      |    80     |
|     Mcdonalds_320x1024      |     320     |   1024    |
....
```

`CREATIVE_SIZE_TABLE` consists of one column

```
| CREATIVE_SIZE |
|   320x480     |
|   1024x320    |
....
```

`REVERSE_CREATIVE_SIZE_TABLE` consists of two columns

```
| CREATIVE_SIZE | REVERSED_SIZE |
|   320x480     | 480x320       |     
|   1024x320    | 320x1024      |
....
```

I have a few conditions that I want to implement:

1. FULL OUTER JOIN MY_TABLE and CREATIVE_SIZE_TABLE ON `NAME` contains `CREATIVE_SIZE`
2. since it's a full outer join, some CREATIVE_SIZEs are NULL, for those NULL values I want to do two things:

   a. check whether their NAME contains the REVERSED_SIZE, if it does, fill the NULL with CREATIVE_SIZE

   b. fill the rest of the NULL with BANNER_W and BANNER_H (in aaaxbbb format)

So far I only have this, i'm not sure how to add `a.` and `b.` in my sql statement:

```
SELECT CREATIVE_NAME, AD_BANNER_W, AD_BANNER_H, CREATIVE_SIZE
FROM CREATIVE_SIZE_TABLE cst
    LEFT JOIN CREATIVE_SIZE cs
    ON cst.CREATIVE_NAME ILIKE '%' || cs.CREATIVE_SIZE || '%'
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: don't use FULL OUTER JOIN -- just use left join.

Comment: @Hogan I edited it. do you have a suggestion on how to tackle my problem?

Comment: yes I answered below -- you asked while I was working on typing it out :)

Comment: Interestingly enough, you mention that CREATIVE_SIZE_TABLE has one column (CREATIVE_SIZE) and yet your sql show it having a second column called CREATIVE_NAME ....

Comment: @camba1 that's not true

Comment: is there other data you need from CREATIVE_SIZE or REVERSED_SIZE, or other data that they both have that not just doing the text join of the banner values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same code as Hogan posted, but using CONTAINS to avoid string manipulation in the WHERE clause

```
WITH my_table AS (            
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
       ('320x480_Toyota', 320, 480)
      ,('Tim_Horton_IO00122_1024x320', 1024, 320)
      ,('Walmart_IO00134', 80,  80)
      ,('Mcdonalds_320x1024', 320, 1024)
    v(name, banner_w, banner_h)
), creative_size_table AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    ('320x480' ),
    ('1024x320')
    v(creative_size )
), reverse_creative_size_table AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
    ('320x480', '480x320' ),
    ('1024x320', '320x1024' )
    v(creative_size, reversed_size)
)
SELECT mt.name
    ,COALESCE(cst.creative_size, rcst.creative_size, mt.banner_w || 'x' || mt.banner_h) as NEW_CREATIVE_SIZE
    ,cst.creative_size AS cst_creative_size
    ,rcst.creative_size AS rcst_creative_size
    ,rcst.reversed_size AS rcst_reversed_size
FROM my_table mt
LEFT JOIN creative_size_table cst ON CONTAINS(mt.name, cst.creative_size)
LEFT JOIN reverse_creative_size_table rcst ON CONTAINS(mt.name, rcst.reversed_size)
ORDER BY 1;
```

gives:

```
NAME                         NEW_CREATIVE_SIZE        CST_CREATIVE_SIZE         RCST_CREATIVE_SIZE         RCST_REVERSED_SIZE
320x480_Toyota               320x480                  320x480                   NULL                       NULL
Mcdonalds_320x1024           1024x320                 NULL                      1024x320                   320x1024
Tim_Horton_IO00122_1024x320  1024x320                 1024x320                  NULL                       NULL
Walmart_IO00134              80x80                    NULL                      NULL                       NULL
```

Comment: Hi Simeon, this works great and is faster than ILIKE. Thank you very much.

Comment: You don't need the select statement for values --> `creative_size_table AS ( VALUES
    ('320x480' ),
    ('1024x320') AS v(creative_size ))` will work just fine.  See https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/values.html.  On some platforms one column tables don't even need the extra `( )` - DB2 is the only place I've tested this.

Comment: `select * from ( VALUES ('320x480'), ('1024x320') AS v(creative_size ));` works but `with creative_size_table AS ( VALUES ('320x480'), ('1024x320') AS v(creative_size ))
select * from creative_size_table;` does not for me. But thanks for the hint, works nice for sub selects but I tend to use CTE's to move then out of visual scope.

Answer (score 3):

Just use left joins and then coalesce to find the non null one.

```
SELECT COALESCE(cs.CREATIVE_SIZE, revs.REVERSED_SIZE, AD_BANNER_W||'x'||AD_BANNER_H) as MYSIZE,
   CREATIVE_NAME, AD_BANNER_W, AD_BANNER_H, CREATIVE_SIZE
FROM CREATIVE_SIZE_TABLE cst
LEFT JOIN CREATIVE_SIZE cs
    ON cst.CREATIVE_NAME ILIKE '%' || cs.CREATIVE_SIZE || '%'
LEFT JOIN REVERSE_CREATIVE_SIZE_TABLE revs
    ON cst.CREATIVE_NAME ILIKE '%' || revs.REVERSED_SIZE || '%'
```

Note: while this will work doing a LIKE is always very slow -- if you do this a lot you probably want to do some pre-processing of the data to speed up your queries -- if this is a one off then it does not matter.